# HTML Table to JSON from another URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

Hey guys i am using this `lib` to convert `html` table to `json array`.

http://lightswitch05.github.io/table-to-json/

With this my table is transformed into many objects and it shows it in the chrome console.

It works when i am on the same page as the table but i want to get the `json` onto another page. Initially i did this to target my element and get it to transform it but no luck any ideas?

```
$.get("http://support.jonar.com/support/default.asp?W2305", function(data) {
    var table_csv = $("table.testtable").html(data); //this gives me the entire html doc
    console.log(table_csv);
    var myjson = $(table_csv).tableToJSON();
});
```

This returns the whole document.. for `table_csv`. Also when i store the html `<table></table>` into a variable and i run `$(table_csv).tableToJSON();` i get an empty value i only see `[]`

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Range.createContextualFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment) to turn the data into an [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment).

Then, you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment/querySelector) to find your table, and get it with jQuery to call `tableToJSON`.

```
var frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(data);
$(frag.querySelector('table')).tableToJSON();
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since it's not working, probably it's because `tableToJSON` requires that the element is placed inside the document to work. So, you can do something like that:

```
var frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(data);
var tbl = frag.querySelector('table');
document.body.appendChild(tbl);
var myjson = $(tbl).tableToJSON();
tbl.parentNode.removeChild(tbl);
```

That way, you append the table to the document temporarly only to get the JSON, and immediately remove it as soon as the json was generated. Leave a comment if that solution doesn't work either.

Comment: `$.get( "http://support.jonar.com/support/default.asp?W2305", function( data ) {
  var frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(data);
  $(frag.querySelector('table.testtable')).tableToJSON();
  console.log(frag);
});` this returns the whole document again.. its really weird. @Buzinas

Comment: @RajaSharma If you log the hole `frag` you're right, but if you log `frag.querySelector('table')`, you're not.

Comment: ok so the `frag.querySelector('tabletest')` worked.. when i store this in a variable and try to use it with `console.log($(mytable).tableToJSON());` the array is empty @Buzinas Thanks buddy

Comment: it worked well it generates many objects... can i ask you another question in chat? @Buzinas

Comment: @RajaSharma sure, feel free ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91424/discussion-between-raja-sharma-and-buzinas).

Comment: Hey @Buzinas can you help me again? msg me rajat@jonar.com! :)