# AJAX & JSON: Apply tableToJSON() to data received via ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am requesting an HTML page via Ajax.

That page contains a `<table id="studentsTable" ..` that i want to convert to JSON with the `tableToJSON()` function:

```
    $.ajax({ url:'https://domain.org/en/courses/1226/course_applications', 
  success: function(data) { 

      var $html = $(data);
      var $table = $html.find('#studentsTable').parent();
      console.log($table.html()); //This prints correctly the <table>..contents..</table>

      var tableJ = $table.tableToJSON();
      console.log(tableJ);  //This prints Array[0] !!
      }
    });
```

I am doing the `parent()` thing because if not, the `<table>` and `</table>` tags were chopped off.

**My problem is that** i new into jQuery and obviously **i am doing something wrong when calling** `tableToJSON()`

The aim is, given a table like this:

```
<table border="1" id="studentsTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Old</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>N</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Clare</td>
        <td>Lander</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Y</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

to **get a JSON object** shaped like this (for further processing within a Chrome-extension -but this will be a different question- ;)

```
[
{
    "Name": "John",
    "Surname": "Smith",
    "Age": "40",
    "Gender": "M",
    "Old": "N"
},
{
    "Name": "Clare",
    "Surname": "Lander",
    "Age": "34",
    "Gender": "F",
    "Old": "Y"
}
]
```

Thanks in advance for your patience and tolerance!

Answer (score 1):

Although `tableToJSON` must be some sort of custom function or plugin (not standard jQuery), so it's hard to be certain, nevertheless I think the answer is simple: Do

```
var $table =  $html.find('#studentsTable');
```

Using `.parent()` will get you whatever element is above it, which will not be a table. I suspect if you feed somethng which is not a table to a "tableToJSON" method, then it will fail.

The reason you can't see the "table" tags when you do `console.log($table.html());` is because the `.html()` method only prints the inner HTML of the selected element - see the example in the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/html/ . I suspect this has misled you into passing the wrong element into your function.

Comment: Most likely the OP is using https://github.com/lightswitch05/table-to-json

Comment: Dear @ADyson, thanks for your answer. What you suggested makes sense, but now tableToJSON returns an empty array: []  On the other hand, yes Tomalak, tableToJSON requires an additional library: https://github.com/lightswitch05/table-to-json

Comment: @Pakosis not when I run it, it doesn't. Works perfectly. Check that you're definitely passing it the right item. P.S. You'll get a more readable result if you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(tableJ));`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after many different attempts, i found the sollution in [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956805/html-table-to-json-from-another-url), which i copy&paste the ***why*** here.
As @Buzinas says:

> it's not working, probably it's because tableToJSON requires that the
>   element is placed inside the document to work. You have to append the table to the document temporarly only to get the JSON, and immediately remove it as soon as the json was generated.

Somehow i knew that, so i was trying things like this

```
var table= $('#studentsTable', $(data)).tableToJSON();
```

hoping to provide a differetn `context` to tableToJSON, but didn't work (i dont nknow why).
I also dared to edit the IIFE tableToJSON function inside `jquery.tabletojson.js` source code but again was getting wild..
Good now i can move on!